# Problem In Looping JSON

Tags: jquery, json

I want to append data to selectbox. But, I got this error...

> "Error: $("").attr("value", guruMapelId).html is not a function
>   Source File: http://localhost:8084/controller?aksi=kurikulum
>   Line: 5"

this is my js code:

```
function dataGuruMapelSelect(dataSelect){
    $.getJSON("controller", "aksi=dataGuruMapel", function(json){
        $.each(json.guruMapelData, function(k,v){
            var guruMapelId = v.guruMapelId;
            var guruNama = v.guruNama ;
            $('<option />').attr('value',guruMapelId).html(guruNama).appendTo(dataSelect);
        })
    });
}
```

And this is the JSON data

```
{
    "guruMapelData": [
        {
            "guruMapelId ": "1",
            "guruNip ": "1331/001",
            "guruNama ": "HARI BUDIYONO DRS.",
            "mapelNama ": "PPKn",
            "tahunAjarNama ": "2010/2011",
            "mapelKategoriNama ": "Normatif",
            "mapelId ": "1"
        },
        {
            "guruMapelId ": "2",
            "guruNip ": "1331/002",
            "guruNama ": "PENI WARDAYANI DRA",
            "mapelNama ": "Kewirausahaan",
            "tahunAjarNama ": "2010/2011",
            "mapelKategoriNama ": "Produktif",
            "mapelId ": "2"
        }
    ]
}
```

What is my fault?
Thanks before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a tricky one. If you pass `undefined` to `attr` (`attr('value', undefined)`) or `html` (`html(undefined)`), it will actually be the same as calling `attr('value')` or `html()`, which both return a string and not a jQuery object.

*But wait*, you say, *I'm not passing `undefined`, I'm passing the values of  `guruMapelId` and `guruNama`!*

Let's have a closer look: **The keys in the JSON all have a *trailing space***. That means, `v.guruMapelId` does not exist (hence is `undefined`). You would have to access the data with

```
v['guruMapelId '] // <-- note the trailing space
```

Same for `guruNama`. But better would be to create proper JSON.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/x29aM/)

Answer (score 4):

Your JSON keys contain spaces after their names, so the key is `"guruMapelId "`, not `"guruMapelId"`. You can either remove the space from your JSON keys or use `var guruMapelId = v["guruMapelId "];` and `var guruNama = v["guruNama "];` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check what you get in your $.getJSON (just use alert(guruMapelId) and guruNama ) call then you can just make your option as follow:

```
$('<option />').val(guruMapelId).text(guruNama)appendTo(dataSelect);
```